# Calling JLINK Library Function With Pointers from Python

Tags: python

I am a very new to Python.

I am trying to read a value back from an STM32F4 via a Segger J-Link using a function with the following prototype :-

```
U32 JLINKARM_ReadMemU16(U32 Addr, U32 NumItems, U16 *pData, U8 *pStatus)
```

I have called DLL functions before in Python, but never using pointers, and having looked around the internet I have found various examples using ctypes etc but can't get anything working so stress levels currently going through the roof which probably isn't helping the situation!

Can anybody give me an example of how to call this function successfully?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Hi @halfer, ok thanks for the advice.